# UINavigationController does not work on UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

I need to take photo from the library and set it to `UIImageView`.

I have a class which is UIViewController which implements the delegates `UINavigationControllerDelegate` and `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`

In my code I have implemented the delegate methods,

```
-(void) addPhotoPressed: (id)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *pickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {
        pickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        pickerController.allowsEditing = YES;
        pickerController.delegate = self;
        [self presentViewController:pickerController animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    if (image == nil)
        image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    // Do something with the image
    [cardView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image]];
}
```

Problem is the navigation bar items `Cancel` and `Photos` button does not work.

Can someone please point out if I am missing anything in the code?

My Screenshot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqVW7.png

My .h file

```
@interface AlterDesignView : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate,     UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
{

    UIScrollView * mainScroll;
    UILabel * cardTitle;
    UIView * cardView;
    UISlider *colorSlider;
    UIButton *addPhoto;
    UIButton *saveContinue;


}

@property(nonatomic,retain) UIScrollView *mainScroll;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UILabel *cardTitle;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIView *cardView;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UISlider *colorSlider;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIButton *addPhoto;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIButton *saveContinue;
```

Comment: have you added <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate>

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre yes, i have

Comment: [self presentViewController:pickerController animated:YES completion:nil]; try like this

Comment: @TamilKing i tried, but still the same problem

Comment: @StasDerpoliuk i cleaned the project and deleted derived data. still the same

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImagePickerController *image_picker = [UIImagePickerController new];
    image_picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    image_picker.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
    image_picker.delegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:image_picker animated:YES];
```

Trl like this. This work for me... I hope it wil be helpful to you

Comment: @erdemgc: I think problem not in presentModalviewcontroller.. You share your code I ll check and tell your problem